# How to expose internal domain access only to the repositories

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Lets consider this simplified model:

a Subscription class:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Subscriber> Subscribers => _subscribers.AsReadOnly();

    private readonly List<Subscriber> _subscribers;

    public Subscription(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
    }

    public Subscriber AddRecipient(Recipient recipient, ReceivingMethod receivingMethod)
    {
        var subscriber = new Subscriber(this, receivingMethod, recipient);
        _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
        return subscriber;
    }

    internal bool RemoveSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber)
        => _subscribers.Contains(subscriber) && _subscribers.Remove(subscriber);
}
```

a Recipient class:

```
public class Recipient
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Recipient(string address) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), address)
    {
    }

    internal Recipient(Guid id, string address)
    {
        Id = id;
        Address = address;
    }

    public Subscriber Subscribe(Subscription subscription, ReceivingMethod receivingMethod) 
        => subscription.AddRecipient(this, receivingMethod);
}
```

and a Subscriber

```
public class Subscriber : Recipient
{
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
    public ReceivingMethod ReceivingMethod { get; set; }

    internal Subscriber(Subscription subscription, ReceivingMethod method, Recipient recipient)
        : base(recipient.Id, recipient.Address)
    {
        Subscription = subscription;
        ReceivingMethod = method;
    }

    public bool Unsubscribe() 
        => Subscription != null && Subscription.RemoveSubscriber(this);
}
```

A `Subscriber` results as a `Recipient` subscribes to a `Subscription` and as such the instanciation of that object is internally prohebited. At this point I need to load and populate existing `Subscriber`s from within a repository, which implementation resides in a different namespace (.Infrastructure) and cannot access *internals* of the domain due its protection level.

I strugle to find the right approach. I considered adding the **infrastructure** layer as a *friend* to the **domain** and allowing internal access, but this would make the **domain** dependend on the **infrastructure**, while I wan't it to be independent. Right now the **domain** holds the repositories interfaces, I could add abstract implementations of these, containing access to the models and requiring additional implementation and the injection of a persistence context but this doesn't feel right.

Can someone explain how this is usually done in a rich domain model.

> P.S.: This is an architectureal question at application level and as such I think it fits best in SO.

Answer (score 2):

As @maxdoxdev stated: there probably isn't much wrong with rather having domain classes with a public constructor.

If you feel that you definitely do *not want* public constructors then you could opt for a public factory method on the relevant class or use primitives in your `Add` methods in order for the method itself to internally instantiate the required object(s).

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there is nothing wrong to expose Domain models to repositories as well as the other layers of onion architecture. It would be wrong other way round (expose other layers to Domain).

Furthermore - if your domain model is well encapsulated, and classes are protecting themselves from being created (or put) in anyhow incorrect state, blocking access to those classes seems to be pointless, as nothing wrong can happen to them being instantiated anywhere in your application as long as that part of application has enough information to create those objects.

Onion architecture is allowing dependency to the inside of the onion (so towards the domain).

Please refer to that image: 
https://www.codeguru.com/imagesvr_ce/2236/Onion1.png

or the full article: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/understanding-onion-architecture.html

Exposing Domain to outer layers of onion architecture is giving you some possibilities like implementing the CQRS pattern, still maintaining Queries, Commands inside the Domain - and therefore maintaining validations in one place etc.

### EDIT:

Another thing that I am using a lot is the Application Layer, that is an orchestrator of all the dependencies, and holder of public API.

Application is holding the Interfaces of repositories, infrastructures and other external dependencies. Those interfaces are implemented in various layers and altogether is injected in the Persistence (UI) layer with IoC.

That gives you the flexibility to replace implementations from outer layers, still having application layer not touched at all, as it only relays on abstractions.

*Example:*

Controller - accepts DTO and maps it to Query or Command

Application - handles Query or Command by calling abstractions from outer layers and real implementations of Domain

Domain - has rich models that know how to do business actions

Repositories - just implementations of data access

Take a look at this GitHub:
https://github.com/matthewrenze/clean-architecture-demo
That is also related to great Pluralsight video if you are interested.

Comment: So you suggest to mark the `Infrastructure` as a friend assembly of the `Domain` which implies that the `Domain` contains the `InternalsVisibleTo("Project.Infrastructure")` and I assume as such it would know about the existence of the `Infrastructure`

Comment: I would suggest having it publicly open, as there is no reason I can think of to close it down. (I've edited the answer)

Comment: I don’t argue that the domain should not be exposed to the outer layers, it’s clear that this is the way a domain layer works. I am wondering if it‘s a bad practice to expose the internals of the domain, which you usually do for testing purpose only

Comment: I agree you want to hide the implementation details but I would say that internals should be hidden inside domain classes. If you have an object that is some sort of "domain helper" that is only used internally, then I'd probably make that one class internal and have a domain model class that uses in underneath (either in constructors or via private methods). Doing so protects what you want to be hidden and expose only the so-called public API to the outer layers.

Comment: Thanks for the details and links, you got my upvote for that, but I removed the accepted answer, as it doesn't answer the core of my question. Just to make it more clear: the constructor of the `subscriber` is not publicly available for the reason that a subscriber without doesn't exist without a context.

Comment: As described in the question, a `Recipient` (or call it user) becomes a `Subscriber` by subscribing to a specific `Subscription`, which is the aggregate root. This is actually the business requirment. As such the the `Subscribtion` creates a `Subscriber` when a `Recipient` subscribes to it, as seen in my above code example. I think this is all still valid within DDD. However you (and **@EbenRoux**) helped my come up an answer, that I posted here, just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I will add an answer to my own question as the existing one while leading in the right direction but lacking concreteness about the example given, in case others are interested in a different approach / concrete implementation.

As the `Subscriber` is a product of a `Recipient` subscribing to a specific `Subscription`, which here is the **aggregate root** and as such initially responsible for creating the `Subscriber`, which it still does but in addition I made the constructor of the `Subscriber` public, in order to allow adding loaded entities.

Making the constructor of the `Subscriber` public introduced me to the challange to assure the new `Subscriber` is in a valid state. By this I mean that aswell the `Subscriber` points to a `Subscription` as that `Subscription` is also containing that `Subscriber` in it's collection of *Subscribers* and other dependencies that before were handled by the `Subscription` creation. The solution in the end seems rather simple (in the end) and consisted by adding an internal method to add the `Subscriber` to the `Subscription`'s *Subscribers* and apply the other rules, which previously was only available by "subscribing" a `Recipient`.

So, I enrichted the `Subscription` class:

```
internal void AddSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber)
{
    if (_subscribers.Contains(subscriber)) return;

    _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
    subscriber.Subscription = this;
}
```

And changed the `Subscriber` constructor:

```
public Subscriber(Subscription subscription, ReceivingMethod receivingMethod, Recipient recipient)
    : base(recipient.EMailAdress, recipient.FirstName, recipient.LastName, recipient.Salutation)
{
    Subscription = subscription;
    ReceivingMethod = receivingMethod;
    subscription.AddSubscriber(this);
}
```

Now the Repository is able to instanciate the `Subscribers` from the loaded persistence model.

> I am still open to a better approach and/or details about the downsides of this approach.